# Images not showing on category page

Tags: magento2, product-images

Images of all products not showing on the category listing page, however on the product description page it is showing.
I have already done

> Uploaded new image and set base, small and thumbnail
>
> php bin/magento catalog:image:resize
>
> chmod -R 0777 media/
>
> changed theme to Luma still no result.

Comment: Did you try php bin/magento indexer:reindex? I know i had some issues with that too but worked with a reindex.

Comment: yes i tried reindexing also.

Comment: Can you share site URL. Did you inspect the view source for image path and does that folder exist on your server. As we need to identify if its a permission issue with image not existing or is it due to some bug in the Magento code or due to some module installed. In some Magento cases it has been observed that this issue existed after upgrade

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps to resolve mentioned issue:

**Step-1**. bin/magento indexer:reindex

You will receive a similar result as presented below:

```
Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Category Products index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Categories index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Price index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
Product EAV index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
Catalog Search index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
Stock index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Rule Product index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
Catalog Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
```

**Step-2**. Re-generate the image catalog by using the command below via CLI:

bin/magento catalog:image:resize